# No tengo la opción de web-HTML File en Spring Boot (java)

Tags: java, html, eclipse

Estoy tratando de crear la url index.html para el controlador, y al ir hacia new/other/... me debería aparecer web/HTML File pero ni siquiera me aparece la opción web. Ya intente tratando de descargar Thymeleaf desde el MarketPlace como vi que comentaron en otra pregunta, pero no me aparece Thymeleaf en el market. Agradezco la ayuda.

Comment: Que IDE estas usando?

Comment: Estoy usando directamente el workspace de spring(Spring Tool Suite 4), pero uso Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

me funcionó instalar desde Marketplace: Eclipse Web Developer tools ya que  parece que las ultimas versiones del sts ya no trae el plugins web instalado o puedes crear un archivo File y cambiarle la extensión .html, espero funcione.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que instalar el plugin Thymeleaf desde Eclipse Marketplace.

Luego saldría desde New --> Other... --> Other --> HTML File.

Comment: si te fijas dice que eso ya lo intentó, te recomiendo leer este artículo [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)